# Aligning divs to work in all browsers >= IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have some nested `<div>` elements, and I want to display them as follows:

```
 A  B  C
 D  E
```

As well need to occupy the full page. I tried to set `width: 100%` but not working in IE browser.by specifying  as some pixels its working in all browsers. but that time how can i give pixels to occupy the full page ? So any one help me on this above design to occupy the full page and working in all browsers.

#### HTML:

```
<div class="root" style="width:100%">
    <div>
        <div>A</div>
        <div>B</div>
        <div>C</div>
    </div>
    <div>D</div>
    <div>E</div>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
.root > div {
    display :inline-block;
}
```

Please refer below fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yQpx6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your html isn't very consistent. You could change it too

**HTML**

```
<div class="root" style="width:100%">
    <div>
        <div>A</div>
        <div>B</div>
        <div>C</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>D</div>
        <div>E</div>
    <div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.root > div > div 
    {
       float:left;
       width: 33%;
    }
```

*JSFiddle*: http://jsfiddle.net/yQpx6/3/

OR

**HTML**

```
<div class="root" style="width:100%">

        <div>A</div>
        <div>B</div>
        <div>C</div>

        <div>D</div>
        <div>E</div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.root > div 
{
   float:left;
   width: 33%;
}
```

*JSFiddle:* http://jsfiddle.net/yQpx6/4/

Comment: This displays each root div side-by-side, rather than under one another... http://jsfiddle.net/yQpx6/2/

Answer (score 1):

u can easily build this by `float:left` but if can add one more `<div>` that hold the D and E div then it would work.

some modification would be a follows

```
<div class="root" style="width:100%">
    <div>
        <div class='floatleft'>A</div>
        <div class='floatleft'>B</div>
        <div class='floatleft'>C</div>
    </div>

    <div style='clear:both'> 
        <div class='floatleft'>D</div>
        <div class='floatleft'>E</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css would be

```
.floatleft
{
    float:left;
    padding:2px;
}
```

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mayekarsaurabh/yQpx6/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try :

CSS

```
.root div > div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="root" style="width:100%">
<div>
<div>A</div>
<div>B</div>
<div>C</div>
</div>
<div>
<div>
    D
</div>
<div>
    E
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div class="root" style="width:100%">
    <div>A</div>
    <div>B</div>
    <div>C</div>
    <div>D</div>
    <div>E</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.root > div 
{
float:left;
display:inline-block;
width: 33%;
}
```

The width will be the space between your divs. This means whatever width your divs have you can manually decide the spaces/number of divs/line.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/yQpx6/6/

Comment: Why does it needs float: left ?

Comment: You can make it work using only float:left; or only display: inline-block; But I normally do both to prevent any wierd things happening.

Comment: Well, float means you break the current HTML normal float, inline-block means you give the element the behaviour of both inline and block element. Usually, you should use one or the other property, as it's two different way of positionning content. if you need this positioning to work in IE8-, use float method, if it's IE9+, go inline block (and others). The thing is weird things will happen doing this. Basically, you'll need to restore the normal float after this code, when inline-block should avoid this.